# Confusion with ambiguity of functions and correspondences

Tags: combinatorics, functions, discrete-mathematics

I know questions similar to this have been asked before, however I felt this question was specific enough to justify asking it again. If not, please mark it as duplicate and I will refer to the other answers.

In my textbook, the term "function" often seems to be used with different meanings in different contexts. For example, take this particular counting problem:

> How many functions are there from the set $\{1, 2, \ldots n \}$, where $n$ is a positive integer, to the set $\{0, 1\}$
>   b) that assign 0 to both 1 and $n$?

I think that there are $0$. In fact, earlier in the same textbook, it states:

> a correspondence which sends an element to two different elements is not a function

However, the solution book also refers to it as a function in its explanation:

> If the function assigns $0$ to both $1$ and $n$, then there are $n - 2$ function values free to be chosen. Each can be chosen in 2 ways. Therefore, by the product rule (since we have to choose values for all the elements of the domain) there are $2^{n-2}$ such functions, as long as $n > 1$. If $n = 1$, then clearly there is just one such function.

Once again, by stating there are still two available values to assign to elements in the domain, does the question not violate the requirements of a function a second time?

I would appreciate some help clearing up these (seeming) inconsistencies. Is my understanding flawed? Is this looser definition just something I have to figure out by context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem seems more of a language issue than a mathematical issue to me. Note, however, that learning the language in mathematical texts is also something that takes time and practice, so there is no shame in getting it wrong from time to time.

You interpret it as $f(0) = 1$ and at the same time $f(0) = n$. You are right that this would not be called a function (unless $n = 1$, that is).

However, if you look at the original sets, which way $f$ goes, and the answer, you will see that they really meant that $f(1) = f(n) = 0$ (the biggest hints here are that there is no $0$ in the domain of $f$, which goes from $1$ to $n$, and $n$ cannot be in the range, which consists of just $0$ and $1$). In other words, it is not that one input number is asociated to several different output numbers at once, but rather that several input numbers are associated to the same output.

Comment: Thank you for the clear and helpful answer. Much appreciated!